# How to protect single column in excel generated through angular

Tags: angular, excel, exceljs

I am trying to protect a column of excel that has been generated through exceljs package in angular. It works fine when I open it in Excel-2019. But when I open in Excel-2007, all the columns are editable.

```
downloadExcel2(payload, fileName): void {
    let workbook = new Workbook.Workbook();
    let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('data', { state: 'visible' });

    const header = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8", "Col9"]

    let data = [];
    data = payload.map(Object.values);

    let headerRow = worksheet.addRow(header);

    headerRow.eachCell((cell, number) => {
      cell.fill = {
        type: 'pattern',
        pattern: 'solid',
        fgColor: { argb: 'FFFFFF00' },
        bgColor: { argb: 'FF0000FF' }
      }
      cell.border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, left: { style: 'thin' }, bottom: { style: 'thin' }, right: { style: 'thin' } }
      cell.protection = { locked: true }
    });

    headerRow.eachCell((cell, rowNum) => {
      cell.protection = { locked: true };
    });

    // Add Data and Conditional Formatting
    data.forEach(d => {
      let row = worksheet.addRow(d);

      for (let j = 1; j<= 9;j++) {
        if (j !== 7) {
          let qty = row.getCell(j);
          let color = 'DADBDD';
          qty.fill = {
            type: 'pattern',
            pattern: 'solid',
            fgColor: { argb: color }
          }
        }
      }
    });

    worksheet.protect('password', {
      formatCells: true,
      formatColumns: true,
      formatRows: true,
      insertRows: true,
      insertColumns: false,
      insertHyperlinks: true,
      deleteRows: true,
      deleteColumns: false,
      sort: true,
      autoFilter: true
    })

    worksheet.getColumn(7).protection = { locked: false, lockText: false };
     workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data) => {
        let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName + new Date().getTime() + 'xlsx');
    });
  }
```

When I googled this issue, I found this link that says its an algorithm issue in exceljs.
https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/2275

Is there any way to handle this or I need to change the package.

Thanks